# How to use deprecated functions in boring SSL?

Tags: base64, aes, boringssl

I would like to convert AES128 encrypted text into base64 encoding using boringssl in android. I am using functions like "BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());" to accomplish this. The compile process fails saying undefined reference to 'BIO_f_base64()'.

On further debugging I found out that while this works with openssl it wont work with boringssl since the function is deprecated.

Below is a piece of code showing base64 encoding (this works perfectly fine with openssl):

```
BIO *bio, *b64;
BUF_MEM *bufferPtr;

b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); 
BIO_write(bio, buffer, length);
BIO_flush(bio);
BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, &bufferPtr);
BIO_set_close(bio, BIO_NOCLOSE);
BIO_free_all(bio);

*b64text=(*bufferPtr).data;

return (0); //success
```

BoringSSl contains a seperate directory for deprecated functions wherein 'BIO_f_base64()' is defined. How may I use this ?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was enough to include `src/decrepit/bio/base64_bio.c` in the build.

Note: I won't vouch for the security of using anything other than the default BoringSSL build :)

Answer (score 0):

The function is compiled into the `decrepit.lib` which is not part of the installation. You can add it by appending the line

```cmake
install_if_enabled(TARGETS decrepit EXPORT OpenSSLTargets ${INSTALL_DESTINATION_DEFAULT})
```

to `decrepit/CMakeLists.txt`.

Then you can link to the target `OpenSSL::decrepit` in your CMake code.